# A government agent asks his evil doppelganger how he (the real agent) broke his arm when he was 10 years old

Tags: story-identification, tv

A government agent is replaced by an imposter, who has had plastic surgery to pull off the switch.  When the agent asks the imposter how he (the real agent) broke his arm when he was 10 years old, the evil imposter knows even that obscure fact about the man he is impersonating.

This was an older TV show, something I would have seen on reruns. (As in, Alfred Hitchcock Presents or Mission Impossible--something along those lines.)

Comment: was it set in "current day" (for the time) or more sci-fi? I'm thinking along the lines of Man from U.N.C.L.E. / Mission Impossible vs UFO or The Invaders which all had some element of imposters at some stage.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it might be the movie [Who?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%3F_(film))

> An enigmatic individual with a metal face is returned from East Germany and claims to be Lucas Martino, an American scientist who was working on a top-secret project but was severely injured and scarred in a car crash. American authorities hold him in custody while they try to establish whether the man is the real Martino – or an impostor.

The film consists of scenes of "Martino" being questioned, alternating with flashbacks to a Soviet agent being schooled to impersonate the real Martino.

I don't recall if they asked him about a broken arm.

Note that he wasn't given "plastic surgery" but a metal face.